# Image Filter by JHlabs in Android

Tags: android, image-processing

I applied several filter of androidjhlabs.jar and its work for me also.
Here is the filter that works:
**GaussianFilter
ContrastFilter
InverFilter
GrayScalFilter
MarbleFilter
WeaveFilter
GainFilter
SolarFilter
HSBFilter**
but i tried some other filter that cant give me proper output some image got converted into black some got converted into white that means i didn't know proper scale ,Randomness,Amount,Turbulence and Gridtype etc.
I tried water filter but its applied only in center point means not in hole image.
here is the code:

```
public static Bitmap setWaterFilter(Bitmap src)
{
int width=src.getWidth();

int height=src.getHeight();

int pixel;

WaterFilter filter=new WaterFilter();

int[] bittoarr = AndroidUtils.bitmapToIntArray(src);

int[] result=filter.filter(bittoarr, width, height);

Bitmap applied = Bitmap.createBitmap(result, width, height,

Config.ARGB_8888);

return applied;
}
```

and i passed source like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.px);
bitmap=Effects.setWaterFilter(bitmap);
im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Any one know how to solve it.means other filter also like BoxBlur,Crop also.

Comment: where it was imported in  AndroidUtils class

Answer (score 0):

this is simple ;-) you just set more parameter to achieve you want like showen below for exaple:

use setRadius to set radius of your wave, use setCenter to point the center of wave, min value is 0 and max is 1 for width and height of your image source;

```
            WaterFilter waterFilter = new WaterFilter();
            waterFilter.setEdgeAction(TransformFilter.WRAP);
            waterFilter.setRadius(350.0f);
            waterFilter.setWavelength(8.0f);
            waterFilter.setAmplitude(0.6f);
            waterFilter.setCentre(0.5f, 0.5f);
            int[] src65 = AndroidUtils.bitmapToIntArray(inter);
            int width65 = inter.getWidth();
            int height65 = inter.getHeight();
            int[] dest65 = waterFilter.filter(src65, width65, height65);
            Bitmap destBitmap65 = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest65, width65, height65, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```